# How to print.summarytools - with our without view() wrapper

Tags: r, visual-studio-2017, summarytools

I'm attempting to create a table (for inclusion into a MSFT Word table) like the one found here:

https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools

3 - descr() : Descriptive Univariate Stats

However,

```
descr(iris, style = "rmarkdown")
style = "rmarkdown" is actually set as an st_options() - see below
```

As indicated in the text, does NOT create the table that follows in the document.

```
view(descr(iris, style = "rmarkdown"))
```

DOES create the table that follows in the document - as do the following.

```
view(descr(iris), "browser")
print(descr(iris), "browser")

view(descr(iris), "viewer")
print(descr(iris), "viewer")
```

The following create the table in a form for "Using pander with knitr" (see: http://rapporter.github.io/pander/knitr.html)

```
view(descr(iris), "pander")
print(descr(iris), "pander")
```

Near as I can tell (at this point), I need to learn knitr (https://yihui.name/knitr/) - working on it.

At the risk of being overly verbose, here is my "environment":

> ```
> R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02) -- "Feather Spray"
> Copyright (C) 2018 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
>
> library(summarytools)
> library(dplyr)
> library(data.table)
> library(pander)
> library(knitr)
> library(rmarkdown)
> ```

<<<<<< sourced at start

```
st_options(bootstrap.css = FALSE, # Already part of the theme so no need for it
           plain.ascii = FALSE, # One of the essential settings
           style = "rmarkdown", # Idem.
           dfSummary.silent = TRUE, # Suppresses messages about temporary files
           footnote = NA, # Keeping the results minimalistic
           subtitle.emphasis = FALSE) # For the vignette theme, this gives much better results.

st_css()

library(knitr)
opts_chunk$set(comment = NA, prompt = FALSE, cache = FALSE, echo = TRUE, results = 'asis')

library(tables)
```

Comment: The function `View` really does just what it says: lets you "view" the data in a specific way. If you want to "print" it, then you probably need to *export* (e.g., `write.csv`, as LauraS suggested) then open in Excel or some other spreadsheet app. (You might have meant "print to a report", for which you should learn about R-Markdown.) For "select", you're going to need to be clearer what you mean by that, as you might mean "copy so I can paste elsewhere", or you might mean `dplyr::select` (though that doesn't seem likely given the context).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have **summarytools** objects printed from *rmarkdown* with *knitr*, you have two options:

1. use the markdown-style outputs by setting `style = "rmarkdown"` & `plain.ascii = FALSE`, which you did correctly using `st_options()`. The knitr chunk option `results` needs to be set to "asis":

   ````
   ```{r, results='asis'}
   descr(iris, style = "rmarkdown", plain.ascii = FALSE)
   ```
   ````

   Since you've set the style and plain.ascii options globally, you can omit those in the function call.

---

2. You can also use the HTML rendering that makes summarytools generate the html code itself, using htmltools under the hood.

   ````
   ```{r, results='asis'}
   print(descr(iris), method = "render")
   ```
   ````

---

It's also a very good idea to include the css in a chunk at the top of your document with the following chunk options:

````
```{r, results='asis', echo=FALSE}
st_css()
```
````

See [this vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/summarytools/vignettes/Recommendations-rmarkdown.html) for more info and examples.

Answer (score 0):

The tab that opens with `view()` isn't meant to be printed or selected, really. Do you mean physically printed out on paper? That's not really what R is for. Try exporting your data to a csv file or something.

```
 write.csv(MyData, "My data file.csv")
```

Comment: `write` is for matrices (according to [`?write`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.3/topics/write)), not frames; this should error with `argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`. Especially since you recommended the `.csv` suffix, did you mean to use `write.csv`?

Comment: oops! Yes, that's what I meant.